# Enhanced Apple Push Notification: Response error at provider server

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

i am working on a project in PHP which requires me to push an alert notification on APNS server. I have used enhanced push notification format. but I am not receiving response as specified by the APNS docs. I am getting response in three digits usually 133, 132, 154, 138, etc. Which I concluded to be Status signs, eg. 133 is 1, 3, 3. but now I have also received 139. so I doubt that my interpretation of response is wrong. But I am not getting where it is wrong. And important thing is though I am receiving these responses Alert is getting pushed and I am receiving notification on my iPhone as well as on iPad.

My code is as follows:

```
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');

$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'; 

$apnsPort = 2195; // default port

$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem'; // APNS crtificate.

$passPhrase = '';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passPhrase);

try{

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

if (!$apns) {
    print "Failed to connect {$error} {$errorString}\n";
}
else {   
    // Sending the payload

    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack('n', 1) . pack('n', $nid) . pack('n', time() + 604800) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $alert_device_token)) .  pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    echo 'APNS Message: ' . $apnsMessage;

    $fwrite = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

    echo 'APNS response: ' . $fwrite;
```

And when this get executed i got the following response printed on the browser:

> APNS Message: ��=ŸÂ� òc6–U:õŸŠ ¸Þ ÷Ä‡Ú0ßqšÊzÂífÕnZ�`{"aps":{"alert":"Your EUR\/USD SELL alert price has been reached!","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}APNS response: 139

Can anyone please tell me what does this 139 means here. am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: may i ask if you fixed it. im getting something like this.

Comment: Hi, Yes I got out of this situation. You have to use enhanced payload instead of this one i.e. normal pay load

Comment: dubbelugh below is correct: the number u receive is the bytes written by fwrite. But u can use this for error checking because if you receive a 0 response back, it means that fwrite was unable to write anything, probably because Apple closed the server connection. So its not the fwrite with the 0 response that is the problem, it is a previous fwrite that was succesfully sent, but there was something about it that apple did not like, so they closed the server connection. If you use "ORDER BY id" with SELECT statement then u can figure out approx where problem occured & continue PUSH from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The echoed "139" is the return value of fwrite(). It's the number of bytes written by fwrite()

See: [PHP: fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)